# How do you call identically named properties on different types which don't share an interface?

Tags: wpf, reflection, interface, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

I have a DataTemplate that needs to set the IsSelected property on an ItemsControl's container (such as TreeViewItem, ListViewItem or ComboBoxItem).  However, it doesn't know the type of the container until it's passed in to it.  Since IsSelected isn't part of a common base class or interface, nor is it a common dependency property registered with AddOwner to the various classes (Duh, MS!!! WTF not?!!), I ended up with this mess...

```
if (container is TreeViewItem) {
    (container as TreeViewItem).IsSelected = true;
    return;
}

if (container is ListBoxItem) {
    (container as ListBoxItem).IsSelected = true;
    return;
}

if (container is ComboBoxItem) {
    (container as ComboBoxItem).IsSelected = true;
    return;
}
```

...which not only is verbose, but requires me to modify it if I ever use a different ItemsControl that uses different container types!  Not good!

Sure I could enhance it a little by putting this logic in extension methods (damn C# for not having extension properties!!) called IsContainerSelected and SetContainerSelected and putting them on UIElement, then moving the above code inside there, but it's just making the outside neater.  The inside is still a mess.

My only other thought is to use reflection and look for an IsSelected property and use that if found, but I'm always leery of doing things like that.  However, since there isn't a common interface or base class, I'm not really sure I have a choice here.

For context, I'm sharing a complex data template between several different ItemsControls and the template itself has controls that can receive focus such as checkbox and textbox.  However, when those controls receive focus via the mouse, the underlying container item doesn't get selected and whatever was selected before remains so.

My workaround is to use an attached behavior that utilizes the preview events to intercept the focus before it happens and set the underlying item accordingly, which works great when I've hard-coded TreeViewItem or ListBoxItem, etc., but I don't want to hard-code the type since the control shouldn't really care.  So that's the part that breaks down.

Ugh!!!  Why didn't MS just register the same attached property or at least create an ISelectableContainer interface?!!

Comment: I know this may sound horrible to some people, but if this is about C# 4.0, you could use a dynamic reference and set the `IsSelected` property only once... :P I guess this has the same benefits/problems than reflection, but with a much cleaner code...

Comment: I'm not (yet) familiar with this.  Granted, I found a solution in my own answer below, but if you have one you can share explaining this, that would be great!  Right tool for the job only works when you know what tools you actually have, right?

Comment: Hey @rsenna... can you elaborate on your comment above?  I never heard back form you on it. Yes, we are using C# 4.0.

Comment: I'll write you an answer so you can understand what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @mdm20's answer, he suggested modifying the ViewModel, which is of course normally what you want to do.  However this is a purely view-related issue (keyboard navigation-related) and isn't reflected in the ViewModel at all, nor in this case should it be.

But that gave me an idea!  Since I'm using a custom control to render the item in whichever items control (via its data template) it's being added to, that control naturally *does* have multiple instances (all of which are pointing to the same ViewModel instance), which is what I want!

Therefore, rather than adding the IsSelected to the ViewModel, I added it to the user control itself, then I just bind to that within the data template for the respective ItemsControl which I do know about.  I can then set the IsSelected property in the code-behind for the user control as needed (i.e. during the preview mouse events, etc.) and the underlying ItemsControl responds appropriately!  Works great and keeps the ViewModel clean since neither the model, nor the viewmodel need to know about it. The IsSelected remains purely in the UI which is where in this particular case it should be!

Answer (score 2):

I have read your answer, and it does make sense - in your case, `IsSelected` may obviously be part of the ViewModel, and that seems to be the best solution in your case.

But you asked for further explanation about C# dynamic features. C# 4.0 now has some dynamic functionalities, which allow us to create code that would only be possible in languages like Python, Ruby or JavaScript. This, of course, has its cost - a `dynamic` abuse would not only make code slower, but also more confusing - because you would lose compile-time errors and IntelliSense.

I have written a simple example so you may understand it better:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public int SameProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    public int SameProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ClassThree
{
    public string SameProperty { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        dynamic wrapper = new ClassOne();
        wrapper.SameProperty = 5;

        wrapper = new ClassTwo();
        wrapper.SameProperty = 15;

        wrapper = new ClassThree();
        wrapper.SameProperty = "Now it is a string!";

        // And now a run-time error...
        wrapper.AnotherProperty = "And this won't work...";

    }
}
```

As you can see, `wrapper` has no definite type whatsoever - a `dynamic` reference will allow any kind of method or property invocation, since the actual binding will only be made during run-time, not compile-time.

Of course, this example is very naive, but sometimes dynamic code may be useful - it is a good option to avoid explicit reflection, or to avoid long `if...else` statements based on type (like your snippet above).

Comment: Actually, that's a really great explanation.  The dynamic keyword--basically a late-binding implementation--looks to be pretty powerful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, but you could try adding an IsSelected boolean to your model and then binding that property against the Item control it's contained in.  That way, you just have to worry about setting that property in the model, regardless of the container.

Comment: Normally that would be the way to go, but the model item can appear in multiple places (think of the tree's folders as keywords and the leaf represents items to which they apply.) Plus this has nothing to do with the viewmodel. This is a UI behavior issue and would apply regardless of the model. The selection is only used for keyboard navigation.  The checkbox is what determines which items are selected and they are bound to the viewmodel (i.e. you check one instance, they all check as they should.)  Again, this is just visual behavior, not model or viewmodel.

Comment: Actually... answered my own question, but your answer gave me the idea so I'm voting you up.